# how to stop local disk sharing on same network? when I'm using XAMPP server

Tags: networking, xampp, sharing

I'm using xampp for php. but it allows other to look at my pc data which are on same network.
How I can stop this?

Comment: By using a firewall or configuring the apache http server such that it only listens on the loopback interface ir that it denies all non-local local request. _Read the documentation..._

Comment: already using firewall... but don't know how to configure apache?

Comment: If you are using a firewall, then you can block the port the apache http server listens on and the issue is solved. Why don't you do that if you are already using a firewall?

Comment: tell me how to config apache configuration file?

Comment: Well, you use a simple text editor, open the file and change it.

Comment: I know that but que is that what code i have to change in config file to stop local network sharing which block others to access my pc using my IP

Comment: I suggest you take a look into that file and read about the basics in the official documentation of the tool you use (the apache http server). Its documentation is of excellent quality and comes with great examples: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html